# Second time method is get in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I got a page where I have a text box when press enter it will call this javascript to submit the form. The form I have set like this . So I notice first time I press enter in chrome it send the data via post. The second time is sending via get. I can see it via the inspect element. But in IE and FF is working perfectly fine.

```
 function checkEnter(e)
{ //e is event object passed from function invocation
    var characterCode;
    // literal character code will be stored in this variable

    if(e && e.which)
    { //if which property of event object is supported (NN4)
    e = e
    characterCode = e.which //character code is contained in NN4's which property
    }
    else
    {
    e = event
    characterCode = e.keyCode //character code is contained in IE's keyCode property
    }
    //alert("Check Enter : "+characterCode);

    if(characterCode == 13)
    { //if generated character code is equal to ascii 13 (if enter key)
    document.forms[0].submit();//submit the form
    return false ;
    }
    else
    {
    return true 
    }
}
```

Comment: please put a second newline before your code

Comment: @jasper where to add the newline? I do not get you.

Comment: In your question, between "But in IE and FF is working perfectly fine." and `function checkEnter(e)`. That way the layout won't be broken on this site.

Comment: is it ok now? I guess so right?

Comment: Yep, much more readable.

Comment: What is the action of the form? Are you sure you are submitting the same form (your code `document.forms[0]` selects the first form in the document, which may change)?

Comment: Yes I am sending to the same form and there is only one form here no other forms.No changes on the form I did.